# Display a JQuery template in a JQuery dialog in a partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

What I'm trying here is to load a JQuery-template with data in a JQuery-dialog in a partial view.
Im quite new to MVC 3, JQuery and JSON so am not very sure if this is right.

I have a Index.cshtml where I have a simple call to the partial view like this:

```
<div id="userList">
@Html.Partial("UserList", new Mvc3Application.Models.User{ Name = "ABC"})
</div>
```

UserList.cshtml

```
@model Mvc3Application.Models.User

@{
ViewBag.Title = "UserList";
}

<div id="edit-popup">
<input type="button" onclick="Call();" id="bnt" /> 
</div>

<script id="edit-template" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">

<input id="edit-id" type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" />
<label>Name</label><input id="edit-name" type="text" value="@Model.Name" />

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 function Call() {

var data = {};
data.Id = "1";
data.Name = "XXX";

alert(data.Name);

$("#edit-popup").html($("#edit-template").render(data));

$("#edit-popup").dialog({
modal: true,
autoOpen: true
});
}
</script>
```

The user model is a very simple one that has these properties.

```
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

Can anyone point me the place im going wrong here. I need the JQuery dialog to display with the template in there with the data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code won't work because you are defining the jQuery UI dialog while you click the call button. Its is plain wrong. You should ideally do this.

Define the dialog on some event like `onDOMReady` and then open the dialog on clicking the button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //render the dialog
    $("#edit-popup").dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
});

function Call() {

    var data = {};
    data.Id = "1";
    data.Name = "XXX";

    alert(data.Name);

    $("#edit-popup").html($("#edit-template").render(data));
    //now open the dialog
    $("#edit-popup").dialog("open");
}​
```

N.B: Please change the function name from `Call()` to something better.

Comment: This change doesn't display the popup. Any other suggestion.

Comment: Ran firebug. Found that on debugging through the jscript, $("#edit-popup").html($("#edit-template").render(data)); it runs upto this line and then the goes back to Call(). I tried commenting this line, it runs through but still the pop up doesnt display the dialog.

Comment: The document.readyState is "Complete". Not sure if this adds any value.